# Прокси сервер на моем компьютере

Tags: proxy

Есть ли такая программа на windows, с функционалом прокси сервера? Чтобы на 2 компьютерах установить эту программу, и с 1 компьютера раздавать ip другому компьютеру, как это делают обычные прокси.

Comment: Есть. Смотрите тут https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8+%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функционал который Вы хотите реализует не прокси сервер а DHCP сервер.

**Прокси-сервер** это служба посредник. Клиент для доступа к какому то ресурсу (например для доступа к https://www.google.com.ua) обращается к прокси серверу и указывает адрес запрашиваемого ресурса, прокси сервер уже связывается с ресурсом и передает клиенту ответ от ресурса.

Прокси сервер нужен для контроля за трафиком (мониторинга и фильтрации запросов)

**DHCP сервер**  — служит для автоматической конфигурации сетевых устройств. Для автоматической конфигурации компьютер-клиент на этапе конфигурации сетевого устройства обращается к нему, и получает нужные параметры. Сетевой администратор может задать диапазон адресов, распределяемых сервером среди компьютеров.

Comment: Вы видимо не поняли, мне нужен прокси-сервер, для 2 компьютеров подключенных к сети. Первый компьютер использует посредник(2 компьютер) для доступа к сайту.

Comment: Так как жеж вас понять когда Вы спрашиваете одно - " с 1 компьютера раздавать ip другому компьютеру", а желаете услышать ответ на другое :). А по теме - Вам нужен Squid (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid)

Comment: Спасибо!.......

Comment: Но там только локальные подключения

Comment: Что значит локальные подключения? к сквиду клиент обращается либо по IP напрямую, либо по сетевому имени (если настроен ДНС сервер или его IP асоциирован в файле hosts с сетевым именем). Прокси сервер может находится с клиентом как в одной сети (пример - обычный офис где прокси служит для контроля посещения сотрудниками тех же соц сетей) так и в разных (пример - луковичная маршрутизация)

Comment: Гуглил, везде только возможность подключения локальной сети. Установил 3proxy, в конфигах просит dns провайдера, у меня его нет. Мне нужно программа, которая сможет использоваться как прокси-сервер для всего интернета, а не только для локальной сети

Comment: весь интернет это совокупность локальных сетей, между ними (сетями) настраивается маршрутизация таким образом что узлы одной сети могут обращаться к узлам другой. В вашем случае прокси такой же узел как и любой другой, у него есть свой айпи адрес, он настраивается на прослушивание определенного порта и если к нему обращаются клиент по его айпи адресу и соответствующему порту он обрабатывает этот запрос. Мне кажется что эта полемика уже выходит за рамки комментариев к посту. Если Вам что то еще непонятно предлагаю перенести общение в скайп или почту.